# Can I use select sql output as an input to Insert sql, in a single stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I wanted to retrieve a value from the select statement and use it in the insert statement. But, both these operations to be done in a single stored procedure. I'm trying something like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Illness_sp (IN DoctorNameIn varchar(255), IN IllnessNameIn varchar(255), IN IllnessSevIn int(10))
BEGIN
select doctorId from doctor where DoctorName=DoctorNameIn;
INSERT INTO Illness(IllnessName, IllnessSeverity, PreferredDoctorId) Values(IllnessNameIn, IllnessSevIn, doctorId);
END
```

I have two statements inside this stored procedure:

1. retrieving `doctorId` from the `SELECT` statement; and
2. wanted to `INSERT` it into another table in the second statement.

Comment: Look at how to assign variables in MySQL stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks much Nick. Your hint helped me.

Comment: …or just use a subquery

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `Illness`(IllnessName, IllnessSeverity, PreferredDoctorId)
SELECT IllnessName, IllnessSeverity, PreferredDoctorId
FROM `SomeTable`
WHERE ...
```